# Asking about how to apply to 2 open positions in same department in same group

Tags: phd, application, application-cover-letter

I am applying to some phd positions in Australian university in Mathematics in Pure maths Dept in same working group ( Number Theory) and 2 professors work in the Field I want to work in and the method of applying is that they have  link of " Apply Now" in the website.

So, There are 2 columns after apply now 1 in which CV is to be uploaded and 1 in which Motivation Letter is to be uploaded.  CV is to be uploaded will be same(obviously).

> But Should motivation/ Cover Letter be same or not?

Let's call professors as Mr. X and Mr. Y. My interest area completely align with Mr.X and there are some regions in which  my Interest doesn't aligns with Prof. Y. But the regions in which Interest aligns with Prof. Y are same as regions in which interest aligns with X.

Kindly Guide me what should I do in this case!

Thank You!

Comment: I can only guess that it should be the same. It seems likely that the two will talk to one another about candidates, as they do about other things. But it is only a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At Australian universities, there are always selection criteria.  If the selection criteria are identical, you can submit identical applications.  If they are not identical, customize your applications to match the selection criteria.

Do address your letter to the correct professor.

If it is true, it would be fine to say in your application that you are equally interested in both positions.  It is quite likely X and Y know each other and are coordinating already.
$ $